# Intermediate problems between L and NL

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, space-bounded

It is well-known that [directed st-connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St-connectivity) is $NL$-complete. Reingold's breakthrough result showed that [undirected st-connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL_%28complexity%29) is in $L$. [Planar directed st-connectivity](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.125.8061) is known to be in $UL \cap coUL$. [Cho and Huynh](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=57031.57034) defined a parametrized knapsack problem and exhibited a hierarchy of problems between $L$ and $NL$.

I am looking for more problems that are intermediate between $L$ and $NL$ i.e., problems that are :

- known to be in $NL$ but not known (or unlikely) to be $NL$-complete and
- known to be $L$-hard but not known to be in $L$.

Answer (score 13):

The RL-complete problem of reachability in directed graphs with polynomial mixing-time (shown by Reingold, Trevisan, and Vadhan in [Pseudorandom walks on regular digraphs and the RL vs. L problem](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1132583)) is in $\log^{3/2}(n)$ space (see $\text{BPHSPACE}(S) \subseteq \text{DSPACE}(S^{3/2})$ by [Saks and Zhou](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcss.1998.1616)), which is strictly between L and Savitch's bound on NL of $O(\log^2 n)$ space.

Answer (score 10):

The RUL-complete problem of reachability in mangroves can be decided in $O(\log^2 n / \log\log n)$ space ([Allender, Lange](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.49.5808), $\text{RUSPACE}(\log n) \subseteq \text{DSPACE}(\log^2 n/\log\log n)$).  A *mangrove* is a directed graph where there is at most one path between any two vertices.

Comment: See also: Lange, "An Unambiguous Class Possessing a Complete Set" STACS '97.

Answer (score 6):

Bipartite Planar Perfect Matching is known to be in $\mathsf{UL}$ (though not in $\mathsf{UL} \cap \mathsf{coUL}$). Since Planar Reachability reduces to it, it is $\mathsf{L}$-hard.

Ref: Samir Datta, Raghav Kulkarni, Raghunath Tewari: Perfect Matching in Bipartite Planar Graphs is in UL. Electronic Colloquium on Computational Complexity (ECCC) [17: 201](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2010/201/) (2010)

Comment: I guess I should be a bit embarrassed about the stale answer - but just for the sake of completeness.