# SC^2 algorithms for st-connectivity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, space-bounded

[Savitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem) gave a deterministic algorithm to solve [st-connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St-connectivity) using $O({\log}^2{n})$ space, implying $NL \subseteq DSPACE({\log}^2{n})$. Savitch’s algorithm runs in time $2^{O({\log}^2{n})}$. It is a major open problem whether st-connectivity can be solved by a deterministic algorithm in polynomial time and $O({\log}^2{n})$ space i.e., whether $NL \subseteq SC^2$. $RL$, which lies between $L$ and $NL$, is [known](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.2997) be in $SC^2$. Hence reachability in directed graphs with polynomial mixing-time is in $SC^2$.

I am looking for special cases of st-connectivity (that are not known to be in $L$) that have $SC^2$ algorithms. Is anything known about planar graphs, planar DAGs ?
 Note that st-connectivity in DAGs remains NL-complete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two related complexity classes in $\text{NL}$ which are also in $\text{LogDCFL}$, which puts them in $\text{SC}^2$ (by [Cook](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=800135.804426)).

- The first is $\text{RUL}$, for "Reach-Unambiguous Log-space" which has reachability in mangroves (graphs where every pair of vertices has at most one directed path between them) as a complete problem.  This class has been [discussed before](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/intermediate-problems-between-l-and-nl/1538#1538).
- The second is $\text{ReachFewL}$, which has reachability complete for graphs with at most a polynomial number of paths between any pair of vertices.

Performing depth-first search on these graphs using a stack has a guarantee that it will take polynomial time, so these classes are in $\text{LogDCFL} \subseteq \text{SC}^2$.

Comment: @Derrick : Please add the references showing that these problems are in LogDCFL.

Comment: @Shiva: I thought the last paragraph was an argument that these problems can be recognized by a deterministic pushdown automaton determined by the graph?

Comment: @András : Yes. I am just curious about the references. They might have connections to other problems and other insights.

Comment: I'm not sure about an original reference for showing they are in LogDCFL, because the proof is one line.

Comment: @Derrick : Thanks. So there are problems in the intersection of NL and LogDCFL that are not known to be in Logspace. Interesting !!

Comment: Yes, very interesting.  Again, mangroves have the (log log n) factor of space efficiency over the savitch bound, but I don't know of a similar bound for ReachFewL graphs.

Comment: The reference for RUL in SC$^2$ is given in Klaus-Jörn Lange, "An unambiguous class possessing a complete set" STACS ’97.

Comment: News from COCOON'11: Now $\mathsf{ReachFewL}$ is [equal to](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2011/060/) $\mathsf{ReachUL}$. Woohoo!

Answer (score 12):

The last complexity conference showed some progress on this question. [Reachability in planar DAGs with $O(\log n)$ sources can be solved in $O(\log n)$ space](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Estolee/Papers/SBV10-LogspacePlanarDAGs.pdf).

Here is also a recent survey by Allender: ["Reachability Problems: An Update"](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-73001-9_3)

Comment: It appears that none of the "intermediate" problems (except RL) are known to be in SC^2.

Comment: @ShivaKintali What do you mean by intermediate problems?

Comment: @Turbo Intermediate problems are those whose complexity lies between L and NL.